# How to achieve this drawable like this using xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create this drawable using xml but unable to figure it out. Please help me to achieve this.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not easy to create custom shapes like this directly using shapes in drawable. What you can do is create the required shape in Image Editing or Design tools like Figma and export them as vectors to use in Android Studio. If you want xml for the shape instead, you can use [this](https://svg2vector.com/) site as well to convert your images into xml drawables.

Here is an example for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="220dp"
    android:height="220dp"
    android:viewportWidth="74.00"
    android:viewportHeight="65.00">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#f35c22"
        android:pathData="M 16.49 0.00 L 74.00 0.00 L 74.00 61.66 L 65.31 53.36 A 1.07 1.06 44.8 0 0 63.84 53.36 L 55.07 61.84 Q 54.61 62.30 54.14 61.84 L 45.49 53.44 Q 44.55 52.52 43.63 53.46 L 35.32 61.90 Q 35.05 62.18 34.77 61.90 L 25.96 53.08 A 0.61 0.60 45.3 0 0 25.12 53.07 L 15.92 61.80 A 0.61 0.61 0.0 0 1 15.08 61.80 L 6.03 53.23 Q 5.64 52.86 5.25 53.21 L 0.00 57.86 L 0.00 16.91 Q 5.44 5.60 16.49 0.00 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M 0.00 0.00 L 16.49 0.00 Q 5.44 5.60 0.00 16.91 L 0.00 0.00 Z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M 74.00 61.66 L 74.00 65.00 L 0.00 65.00 L 0.00 57.86 L 5.25 53.21 Q 5.64 52.86 6.03 53.23 L 15.08 61.80 A 0.61 0.61 0.0 0 0 15.92 61.80 L 25.12 53.07 A 0.61 0.60 45.3 0 1 25.96 53.08 L 34.77 61.90 Q 35.05 62.18 35.32 61.90 L 43.63 53.46 Q 44.55 52.52 45.49 53.44 L 54.14 61.84 Q 54.61 62.30 55.07 61.84 L 63.84 53.36 A 1.07 1.06 44.8 0 1 65.31 53.36 L 74.00 61.66 Z" />
</vector>
```

You can set this as background to your `TextView` and then set the text that you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="30%\nOFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sample Output :

[image: Sample output]